# <Alt> to enter normal mode on Windows

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, microsoft-windows, vim-windows, normal-mode

I'm new to vim, and I find using `<Esc>` to enter normal mode to be slow. I'm on **Windows**. I seldom use the `<Alt>` keys (left and right) when I'm editing text. It should be convenient to use `<Alt>` to enter normal mode instead. What should I enter into my `vimrc` use `<Alt>` instead of `<Esc>` to enter normal mode ?

I found articles online that explain this for MAC, but I could not find one for Windows.

Comment: You’d have to do this at a hardware/OS level, since Alt by itself does not send a code Vim can capture. This how I have Caps Lock perform Control: at the OS level.

Comment: You can't really do what you're asking from vim, you would need to do it on an OS level. This is because vim doesn't handle the key_press and key_release events separately, for vim key_press is the key press. So, the modifier keys really have no way to be mapped to be other keys. I'm not very familiar with windows except from a gamer's perspective, so I'm no help there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Knoble and klaus. Could you please show me how it should be done at the OS level ? Point me to some resource that I can follow.

Comment: Maybe [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: @Ralf thanks! Someone please make a clear answer that this cannot be done in the usual way (requires some hacking). I will accept, and close this. It should be helpful for others (I searched this on the internet for a very long time before I decided to ask here!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> can't be mapped, as it is a "modifier". It is only
detectable if it used together with some other key, like <kbd>Alt-F</kbd>.

To prove that, do the following:

Open Vim, change into insert mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>. Then hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Nothing happens. Only after you hit another key, some input appears.

If you want to map the `Alt` key alone, you have to reassign the `Alt` key on the OS level.  For Windows that might be done with [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (not tested).

BTW: Reassigning <kbd>Alt</kbd> globally will affect all programs, but
Autohotkey seems to have [context-sensitive hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm).

If you want to map `Alt-something`, search Vi and Vim Stackexchange, there are [several questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Alt).